# Rspec raise_error do not work with custom errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a custom error class `ApiError`:

```
class ApiError < StandardError
  attr_reader :message, :code, :details, :raw_json
  def initialize(json)
    @message  = json["message"]
    @code     = json["code"]
    @raw_json = json

    super json.to_s
  end
end
```

So I tried to write several specs to test it and no one passed.
First one:

```
it 'raises an error' do
  expect { raise ApiError, "Some error"}.to raise_error ApiError.new("Some error")
end
```

It failes with:

```
Failure/Error: expect { raise ApiError, "Some error"}.to raise_error ApiError, "Some error"

       expected ApiError with "Some error", got #<ApiError: Some error> with backtrace:
         # ./spec/models/...:39:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
         # ./spec/models/...:39:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

And another option that surprises me a lot:

```
it 'raises an error 2' do
  expect { raise ApiError, "Some error"}.to raise_error ApiError, "Some error"
end
```

It fails with:

```
Failure/Error: expect { raise ApiError, "Some error"}.to raise_error ApiError.new("Some error")

       expected #<ApiError: Some error>, got #<ApiError: Some error> with backtrace:
         # ./spec/models/...:43:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
         # ./spec/models...:43:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

So, what? In the message, they seem pretty equal. Can anyone know what's the problem? And, also, what's the difference writing `ApiError, "123"` and `ApiError.new("123")` in spec files?

==========Upd==========

Commenting out a string with setting a `message` attribute in ApiError class in case it does not overwrite a default value didn't help

```
class ApiError < StandardError
  attr_reader :message, :code, :details, :raw_json
  def initialize(json)
    # @message  = json["message"]
    @code     = json["code"]
    @raw_json = json

    super json.to_s
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`message` is an attribute of `StandardError`. You are overriding it and `message` is `nil` in your exception object. Rename your attribute and it should pass

```
class ApiError < StandardError
  attr_reader :api_error_message, :code, :details, :raw_json
  def initialize(json)
    @api_error_message  = json["message"]
    @code     = json["code"]
    @raw_json = json

    super json.to_s
  end
end

it 'raises an error' do
  expect { raise ApiError, "Some error"}.to raise_error ApiError, "Some error"
end
```

**Update:**

If you need to set `message` to `json["message"]`

```
  class ApiError < StandardError
    attr_reader :code, :details, :raw_json
    def initialize(json)
      @code     = json["code"]
      @raw_json = json

      super json["message"]
    end
  end

  it 'raises an error' do
    expect { raise ApiError, {"message" => "Some error"}}.to raise_error(ApiError, "Some error")
  end
```

Comment: Good point, though this won't solve the OP's problem with the spec.

Comment: @MátéSolymosi, OP needs to rename the attribute because `message` is going to be set to `json["message"]` in `ApiError` initializer and then its going to be set to `json.to_s` in the parent initializer which is misleading in the first place. Also, I tested it locally to make sure the test passes with the attribute rename before posting it here

Comment: Maybe I did smth wrong. I just commented out `message` string in ApiError, but nothing changed. I'll do an update in several minutes to show this in a question

Comment: Oh, I see, it was because I needed to remove `message` from `attribute_reader` too. Why is this important?

Comment: @Ngoral, yes. because `message` is already an attribute of StandardError. When you call `super json.to_s`, it is going to set `message` to `json.to_s`

Comment: I understand, that. But now I wonder what to do if I want to redefine message by redefining `message` attribute to do `raw_json["message"] || super`. It raises exactly what I need and returns a message, but specs still don't pass

Answer (score 2):

Also useful with custom errors is checking properties, which can be achieved with `having_attributes` like so:

```
expect { raise "oops" }
  .to raise_error(
    an_instance_of(RuntimeError)
      .and having_attributes(message: "oops")
  )
```

So you can use any custom attribute like `raw_json` in your example.

[Docs here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing a string to `ApiError.new`, your custom `initialize` method ends up setting the `message` of the exception to `nil`:

```
ApiError.new("Some error").message
#=> nil
```

Try testing with a proper hash instead:

```
let(:error_hash) do
  { "message" => "oops", "code" => 42 }
end

expect { raise ApiError, error_hash }.to raise_error ApiError, "oops"
```

Comment: It worked, but now I wonder why this won't work if I comment out my `message`-string. Answer of usha seems more correct to me, cause it can still be raised by sending a string. Which you are usually expect

Comment: By adding this particular `initialize` function, you made it not work well with just a string, as it interferes with how the message is set.

Comment: The problem seems to be the `:message` attribute reader, as that overrides the `message` method of the parent class.